# Completely Stand-alone gui-application

Tags: user-interface

Which programming language and tools can i use, to develope a complete stand-alone gui-application? This application will be burned on a cd and should run on every windows-pc without any installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really have the time and don't need to deploy on 16-bit Windows, you could always write in Win32 assembly -see [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/) and [Iczelion's Win32 tutorials](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html). There's even a IDE for Win32 ASM -[WinAsm Studio](http://www.winasm.net/) :)

The only dependencies you'll need are the Windows system DLLs which are already there on every Win32 system.

However, if you need to build something quick, something like Visual Basic 6 will do nicely  - it only needs the VB6 runtime by default (1 ~ 2 MB) and that definitely fits into a CD together with your VB6 EXE.

Answer (score 2):

Win32 API.. a similar question was asked today...

Use Visual Studio (you can use express edition) and build whatever you like.

This is the most powerful language, yet development time is very very slow, but the results are:

a. independent.

b. if you a good programmer - small and fast.

one thing - you got to know what you're doing when programming win32...

one Petzold book will get you where you want to go.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711599/what-language-compiler-for-native-running-of-application-in-any-windowsxp-vista/2711655#2711655)

Comment: 3.1 and 3.11 are not a good option for this solution.. but they were cool at that time...

Answer (score 2):

Questions like what your application and what your capabilities are need to be considered.

There are many solutions to your problem. From 'Visual Studio Ultimate' to a HTML file which contains javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for C++ with MFC. Reasonable development times and with static linking it could all be one standalone exe file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to make one of those interactive splash screens, might want to look into Demoshield. I know its old and not supported any longer, but can be of real use for something great looking.

http://www.componentsource.com/products/509937/12838/index.html

You can find copies of it free by google-ing it. Don't think the company is around any longer so not sure if this is legit or not.

But not the right choice if you need to do some serious programming stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi also may be a good choice.